# How the logoutRequests in SAML are signed?

Tags: php, saml, saml-2.0

I'm trying to integrate one Identity Provider in one application we have in PHP. The middleware I'm using in PHP is SamlTool from OneLogin[1](https://www.samltool.com/).

However, when I try to sign the logout Request, that is not working.

I notice that If I try to sign the request and then I check signature they create in their site, is different.

So the question is how is the signature for Saml Logout Request signed.

Answer (score 1):

1. First you need to generate your own cert/public key for instance using site https://www.samltool.com/self_signed_certs.php
2. If you are not using any libray you need to sign the request by yourself example code below in Java
3. To check SAML request/parameters you can use SAML tracer addon on firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/
4. To validate request signature you can use online tool https://www.samltool.com/validate_logout_req.php

Example how to sign the request can be checked here: https://github.com/jrowny/java-saml